# On constant global variables

Tags: c++, constants, global-variables

In c++ programming I want to create a global variable that can be used in  every function without explicitly passing this variable (E.g., `main` calls `f1`, which calls `f2`, which calls `f3`, which uses this variable. Passing all the way down just makes no sense!)

However this variable is input by the user in `main`. (So it can't simply be a const variable outside the `main` function.) Also, I don't want anyone to be able to change it after the input (but anyone can read it). Is there a way to implement this variable?

Comment: You can have a look at the singleton design pattern. However - many people think that it is not much better (if at all) than a global variable.

Comment: *Passing all the way down just makes no sense!*  Nevertheless, that is the best choice, and the other options make much less sense.

Comment: I was once forced to maintain code written by someone who believed as you did, passing parameters was too much trouble.  It was almost impossible to work with, because you never knew what changes you made in one part of the code would affect others.

Comment: Passing some variable to a lot of functions is an indicating that it should be made global. Global variables have their usage and, while it's preferable not to have them, it's absolutely non sense not to have a global variable for the application's main window, for example, or for a synchronization primitive that must be used to control many threads. The maxim 'don't pollute the global namespace' is too low.

Comment: Let's say the data type is a `std::string`, and is set by `main`.  In your `main.cpp` file, you could have a `static std::string user_data;` and a routine `std::string get_user_data() { return user_data; }`.  Then `main` could set `user_data` from user input, and everywhere else in the code could call `get_user_data();`.  Put `extern std::string get_user_data();` in a suitable header, and Bob's your uncle.